# passport-google-oauth2 vs passport-google-oauth20 packages

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-google-oauth2

These 2 packages look very similar:

http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth2/
http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth20/

Is one supersede the other or they serve different purpose? New to Google authentication and still trying to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

[passport-google-oauth20](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth20/) has 10x the use of the other, and it has [more recent commits](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2).

One of the properties in the profile response for [passport-google-oauth2](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth2/) is `isPlusUser`, which suggests that it is not up to date. The readme in the [github repository](https://github.com/mstade/passport-google-oauth2) does not match the [documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth2/), and there are a few links in the passport docs that no longer work.

To be fair, I've only ever used passport-google-oauth20. It's possible that pass-port-google-oauth2 works fine, but there is currently a lot more community support for 20.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I have the same question. It is pretty confusing. One is much more popular than the other. https://www.npmtrends.com/passport-google-oauth2-vs-passport-google-oauth20

Google is using passport-google-oauth20 in their Node tutorial examples. https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/tutorial-app